# Don't understand why this query crashes Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query with a nested query in it like so:

```
select table1.name, table1.address 
       from table1 
       where table1.year=[forms]![form1]![year] 
             and table1.name not in 
             (select table2.name 
                     from table2 
                     where table2.year=[forms]![form1]![year])
```

This crashes Access every time. Am a doing something that isn't allowed?

Comment: if it wasn't allowed, then access would tell you. crashing access is a sign you've encountered a bug, or the query is going down a very deep rabbit hole.

Comment: I realize your sample is just that, but without confirmation it scares me when I see reserved words used.  Have you tried to test your query by first deleting the second condition and testing, then deleting the first condition and test using the second? If they work ok, you may have a corrupted database.

Comment: What are the crash symptoms?

Comment: Sounds like... **corruption** ....

Comment: We have had problems with in() operator in MS Access - try to rewrite query using exists(). Of course start with repairing database - like said above, database corruption is first likely cause for crashing.

Comment: name is a reserved word change it to [name].  Btw.. just join the table1 with table2 on year and your where condition would then be
table1.[name] <> table2.[name] and table1.[year] = your form year.
no need for not in clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using VBA to build my query.

Essentially I wrote a function that sets rs=db.OpenRecordset("my subquery")

Then iterates through rs, and appends it to a string like so:

```
string=""
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
string=string & "'" & rs.Fields(0) & "', "
rs.MoveNext
loop
if string <> "" then string=Left(string,len(string)-2)
```

Finally:

```
strSQL="select table1.name, table1.address from table1 where table1.year=forms]![form1]![year] and table1.name not in (" & string & ")"
```

Then during my afterupdate event

```
me![subform].form.Recordsource=myfunction()
```

Everything works now